# Databricks: Incompatible format detected (temp view)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, parquet

I am trying to create a temp view from a number of parquet files, but it does not work so far. As a first step, I am trying to create a dataframe by reading parquets from a path. I want to load all parquet files into the df, but so far I dont even manage to load a single one, as you can see on the screenshot below. Can anyone help me out here? Thanks
Info: batch_source_path is the string in column "path", row 1
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data is in [Delta](https://delta.io/) format and this is how you must read:

```py
data = spark.read.load('your_path_here', format='delta')
```